# Sum of cubes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, integer

I would like to obtain a list of integers whose cubes add up to a target number. The integers in the list must all be distinct. My code works for all cases except for

```
n=sum([n*n*n for n in range(1001)])
```

...where the expected result is [6303, 457, 75, 14, 9, 7,5, 4] instead my output in my program is [6303, 457, 75, 15, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1]. How can I correct my program to correctly output the expected result?

```
def sum_of_cubes(n):
    original=n
    i=1
    lst=[]
    tot=0
    while i**3<=n:
        i+=1
    lst.append(i-1)
    n-=(i-1)**3
    for j in range(lst[0],0,-1):
        if j**3<n:
            lst.append(j)
            n-=j**3
    if n==1:
        lst.append(n)
    for i in lst:
        tot+=i**3
    #if original-tot>1:
        #return None
    return lst

n=sum([n*n*n for n in range(1001)])
print(sum_of_cubes(n))
```

[image]

Comment: Why are exactly these expected results? For example, for some *n* values there are multiple variants (*e.g.* ***855***: ***[9, 5, 1]*** but also ***[8, 7]***). There must be other things to the problem which you're not sharing.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a backtracking search algorithm using a stack (instead of recursion). Of course, being an exponential algorithm, it only works for inputs of relatively small size.

```py
from math import *

def sum_of_cubes(n):
    bag = []
    stack = [(floor(n**(1/3)), n, [])]                          # simulated initial call
    while stack:
        (k, n, s) = stack.pop()
        if n == 0: bag.append(s)
        elif k > 0:
            stack.append((k-1, n, s))                           # simulated recursive call
            if n-k**3 >= 0: stack.append((k-1, n-k**3, [k]+s))  # simulated recursive call
    return bag
```

Examples:

```py
>>> sum_of_cubes(8)
[[2]]

>>> sum_of_cubes(11)
[]

>>> sum_of_cubes(855)
[[1, 5, 9], [7, 8]]

>>> sum_of_cubes(3473)
[[9, 14], [1, 6, 8, 14], [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 14], [2, 3, 8, 9, 13], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12], [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]]

>>> sum_of_cubes(sum(n**3 for n in range(11)))
[[1, 4, 6, 14], [2, 3, 4, 9, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 13], [1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

>>> sum_of_cubes(15000)
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 12, 23], [3, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 21], [3, 9, 11, 17, 20], [1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 17, 20], [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 17, 20], [2, 3, 5, 14, 16, 20], [3, 5, 9, 14, 15, 20], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 14, 15, 20], [6, 8, 11, 13, 14, 20], [3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 13, 14, 20], [2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 14, 20], [5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 20], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 14, 20], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 20], [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 20], [3, 5, 6, 8, 15, 17, 18], [5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 17, 18], [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18], [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 16, 17], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17]]
```

**Remark** If you are interested in getting *only one* of the possible solutions, you can use this other version of the algorithm:

```
def sum_of_cubes(n):
    stack = [(floor(n**(1/3)), n, [])]
    while stack:
        (k, n, s) = stack.pop()
        if n == 0: return s
        elif k > 0:
            stack.append((k-1, n, s))
            if n-k**3 >= 0: stack.append((k-1, n-k**3, [k]+s))
```

Example:

```
>>> sum_of_cubes(sum(n**3 for n in range(1001)))
[4, 5, 7, 9, 14, 75, 457, 6303]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your algorithm is this:

```
    while i**3 <= n:
        i += 1
    lst.append(i-1)
```

It appends "15" which is lesser than "14"+"9", so your algorytm would not also work for n=3473 for example, wich is 14^3+9^3.

Solution: The only thing I can think of it is maybe to make the forbidden list, basically your algorithm first tries the original one, if it fails, try variants that exclude 1-all member/s of that unsuccessful list...or something like that maybe?

Also you should have checker like:

```
if original != tot:
  doSomething()
  lst=[]
  etc....
```

This should get you to right track, good luck.

EDIT:

Ok so recursive function would solve the problem...if you had infinite CPU power/time, i will show solution to eliminate ONE black member, if there would be 2 or more numbers like 15, it will fail.

```
if original != tot:
  lst= doSomething(original, lst)

doSomething(n,lst):
    returnList=[]
    newList=[]
    orig=n
    for blackMember in lst:
        n=orig
        #basicaly what you wrote before but try add before append and lowering n
        if theNumberYOuWantToAdd != blackMember:
            n -= theNumberYOuWantToAdd**3
            newList.append(theNumberYOuWantToAdd)
    
    ....
    ....
    ....
    if tot == original:
        returnList = newList
    #ofc if you want recursive functions you can do this just...it will freeze on big numbers: 
    #else:
        #superBlastlist = newList + lst #dunno how to connect them, but you have idea
        #returnList=doSomething(orig, superBlastlist)
    return returnList
```

So you have idea...
So basically, for 1-2 levels of blacklisting numbers, it would be CPU acceptable, but i would reccomend dont go above 1e10 combinations, then even GPU helping would not save you :D

2nd Idea:
You can also make a list of A^3+B^3 where it's lower than n, then use that, but it will still be beatable by combinations of A+B+C etc..

Comment: How would you code this?

Comment: Recursive Function, since there would be forbiden lists within forbiden lists for example at  (800^3+11) it will try 800, then 799, then 798 then 797 etc, but even at forbiden 800 it will need to try to forbid all numbers under it...for example 15 :D...chmm....this would be very very CPU heavy...

Comment: Can you show an implementation in code?